# Elasticsearch / Kibana - Wrong time values

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, kibana

I construct an Elasticsearch and Kibana service via Docker. Therefore I use this Github sources: [deviantony/docker-elk](https://github.com/deviantony/docker-elk).

After importing JSON data with a script, Kibana shows me wrong time values. All time values are increased by exactly two hours. Maybe it could be a problem with GMT or UTC time, but I'm not sure. Notice: I work from the timezone Europe/Berlin.

I verified the JSON data, but the time values are correct there. Furthermore, the system datetime of Elasticsearch and Kibana are correct, too.

Unfortunately, I didn't found helpful links for solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

By default Kibana adjusts timestamps to the browser's timezone. This can be disabled in advanced settings.